# Instagram scraping a random list of public profiles

Tags: loops, web-scraping, instagram

Quick summary, I want to create a list or dictionary of random IG profiles (size = ~1000). If possible i would like to set conditions based on number of followers the profiles have. Honestly, I've been searching the last few days for some kind of direction but haven't found anything. I've been using Insta-scrape but it haven't been successful. Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65706671/edit) your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Scraping Instagram is illegal based on their Terms and Conditions so you should have definitely went to do more research before posting this. FBI are probably watching you right now. Scraping other websites legally can be done using requests and beautifulsoup4, or selenium

Comment: easy there, bud. take a chill pill. working on class assignment. thanks for the comment.